# can't install pandas (ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'numpy')

Tags: python, pandas, macos

I'm on macOS 10.15 Beta, running a .py script that requires pandas, which is not installed.

When I run `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pandas` I receive:

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project
>   and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

If I run `sudo pip install pandas` I receive the same error.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solutions presented in the other answers, but what worked for me was installing pandas using conda.

Answer (score 4):

you can try below code.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pandas
```

If still you are not able to uninstall pls share screenshot of error.

Comment: Sry then pls share screen of error when trying 'sudo pip3 install pandas'.

Comment: No problem. I solved it by installing pandas using conda.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative method to install `pandas`, by installing `minicondas`, and running `conda install pandas`.